# why is successful task timing out in web2py scheduler?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, web2py

I am running a task in web2py scheduler.

The task is completing successfully but web2py says that the task is still running until timeout expires and then logs the task with a status of *TIMEOUT*.

Can anyone shed light on this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any code or other details regarding the task and how you are determining success.

Comment: success is determined by reaching the end of the function, with all outputs completed successfully.  I have not posted code because there is just too much of it.  I have stepped through its completion using logging statements and 100% sure that everything is working OK.  I have seen a number of posts regarding this same issue.  At this stage I would be happy with even hypothetical reasons as to why it might not finish.  Also the function has no return value and the logging statements   is approx. 20 lines.

Comment: Can you point to the other posts about this issue -- perhaps that will provide some clues?

Comment: I will try and dig them out later.  From memory the conclusion was that the thread was being blocked due to the size of the return value i.e. the return value was too large or too many log statement.  The changelog for latest version states that a solution has been found to this.  I have no returns and I have minimised the logs and also closed all log file handlers.  Could it possibly be a thread that I am running, but I have no evidence that my functions are misbehaving?