# Web2py scheduler - Best practices to rerun task continuously and to add task at startup

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, web2py

I want to add a task to the queue at app startup, currently adding a `scheduler.queue_task(...)` to the main *db.py* file.  This is not ideal as I had to define the task function in this file.

I also want the task to repeat every 2 minutes continuously.

I would like to know what is the best practices for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no real mechanism for this within web2py it seems.

There are a few hacks one could do to continuously repeat tasks or schedule at startup but as far as I can see the web2py scheduler needs alot of work.

Best option is to just abondon this web2py feature and use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or similar for advanced usage.

Answer (score 4):

[As stated in web2py doc](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#queue_task-), to rerun task continuously, you just have to specify it at task queuing time :

```
scheduler.queue_task(your_function,
                     pargs=your_args,
                     timeout = 120,  # just in case
                     period=120,     # as you want to run it every 2 minutes
                     immediate=True, # starts task ASAP
                     repeats=0       # just does the infinite repeat magic
                     )
```

To queue it at startup, you might want to use [web2py cron feature](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Cron) this simple way:

```
@reboot root    *your_controller/your_function_that_calls_queue_task
```

Do not forget to enable this feature (-Y, more details in the doc).

Comment: I get a down vote for every web2py question!!  I will give this a try, I was also having problems with the task not completing successfully, I always get a TIMEOUT result (this is a larger problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186032/why-is-successful-task-timing-out-in-web2py-scheduler?noredirect=1#comment63814565_38186032).